# Different kinds of quotes in Nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

What is the difference between using a single quote ' or a double quote " in nasm? Does it have any affect on defining variables, or nesting quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [NASM's manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html):

> A character string consists of up to
>   eight characters enclosed in either
>   single quotes ('...'), double quotes
>   ("...") or backquotes (`...`). **Single
>   or double quotes are equivalent to
>   NASM (except of course that
>   surrounding the constant with single
>   quotes allows double quotes to appear
>   within it and vice versa)**; the
>   contents of those are represented
>   verbatim. Strings enclosed in
>   backquotes support C-style -escapes
>   for special characters.

Comment: Not to sound stupid, but why eight characters, what happens if u include more, such as in a buffer for indexing?

Comment: Actually it depends on the architecture (**up to**), 8 characters is valid for 64-bit architectures. For 32-bit architectures you can write for example `mov eax,'abcd'`

Comment: This is a bit misleading.  You're talking about one character literal, but often quoted strings are used as an operand for `db`.  Like `msg: db "hello world!", 0xa, 0`.  There's no limit there: each byte becomes a separate operand for `db`, which takes a list.  Or with `dd`, the string is padded to a multiple of 32 bits at the end.